# Broken Links .htaccess issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I checked my WordPress theme on broken link checker website and its giving me a list of broken URLs.

See:

```
http://www.esmedicare.com/locations.html ( parent page: http://www.esmedicare.com/ )
http://www.esmedicare.com/laser-treatments/locations.html ( parent page: http://www.esmedicare.com/laser-treatments/ )
```

The links with /location.html goes to 404 page and I want to redirect these pages to their parents page. i.e. Just remove the /location.html from URL and to redirect these to their parent URL mentioned in the bracker.

I added code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/locations.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

to my .htaccess file, now some `/location.html` pages are redirecting to their parent page but still not all of them.

Please solve my issue...I just want to remove the `/location.html` from last in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to include the web root (`/`) then you need to make the slash optional:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?locations.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @PhillipMclauren just replace your `RewriteRule` line with this one

Comment: @PhillipMclauren The redirection is [working for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gmBsb.png)